# can not install apache dpkg was interrumpted

Tags: linux, debian, dpkg

Someone who has any idea of why and how to fix this error?

[image]

and after executing the commands of the end 
dpkg --configure -a
shows the following

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First try doing the following:

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure grub-pc
```

then select the correct disk (/dev/sda/) when prompted. In that way, if the error does come back again try the following solution:

```
sudo grub-install /dev/sda
```

then

```
sudo update-grub
```